# iOS 9.x settings blank after 1st launch of an app under development

Tags: ios, shell, build, xcode7, settings

I am having a consistent problem with iOS Settings not showing up after the first launch of a new app. Existing apps appear to be OK.

In the build phase, I have a script which used for some modification but that script has been executed as pre-action.

I compile/build/run in Xcode to Simulator or to iPhone with Xcode 7.2.1.

The first time I run it the settings appears. Run the app again the same way and I get blank sheet where Settings for this app used to be.

I see the Settings for this app just the one time. I can switch back and forth and the Settings remain visible, the blank sheet only appears on 2nd and subsequent launches of the app from Xcode.

The Navigation bar is visible throughout but in the blank case there is absolutely nothing below it excluding system option.

**UPDATE**

I have following code which copies the required `Root.plist` into the main Setting bundle.

```
if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "Release" ]
then
cp "${SRCROOT}/Product_Settings.bundle/Root.plist" "${SRCROOT}/Settings.bundle/Root.plist"
elif [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "Debug" ]
then
cp "${SRCROOT}/Develop_Settings.bundle/Root.plist" "${SRCROOT}/Settings.bundle/Root.plist"
fi
```

Develop_Settings : Development Setting bundle
Product_Settings : Production setting bundle

Comment: can you provide some more information about your code/screenshot about it ?

Comment: @pyro updated the questions with code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I spend a lot of time for investigation and finally realized that its bug with new Xcode 7.x . You need to kill setting application from background in order to see the updated setting after the second launch of the application.

Comment: Is there any other way to do this with out killing settings app. My understanding is when the settings app is in running / background mode , it couldn't read the plist file from the application. A simple relaunch of settings app will solve this issue.

Comment: @MadhanMani, I tried mentioned flow as well, but it did not work for me.